# Trying to find a song from Assassination Classroom episode 19

Tags: music, assassination-classroom

I was watching the first season of Assassination Classroom and I really enjoyed this one song. On episode 19 of season 1, at 5:48, a song starts up that sounds techno-esque and I really like it. Which song is it?

Answer (score 2):

This is track #18 from the [season 1 soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/50984), titled 「エレクトリック会議」 *Electric Kaigi* "Electric Meeting". You can listen to an excerpt from this piece (and the rest of the OST, too) on [the Amazon Japan page for the album](https://www.amazon.co.jp//dp/B00TNF0BZW/).